# Mask for kendo datepicker

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I want to add mask to `DatePicker`. I found in the Internet the following code:

```
(function($) {
    varui = kendo.ui,
     MyMask = kendo.ui.DatePicker.extend({
        init: function(element, options) {           
            varextended = $.extend(this.options, options);
            kendo.ui.DatePicker.prototype.init.call(this, element, extended);
            debugger;
            $(element).inputmask("mask",extended);
        },
        options: {          
            name: "MyMaskedDatePicker",
            mask: "99/99/9999",
            showMaskOnHover: false,
            clearMaskOnLostFocus: true
        }
    });

    ui.plugin(MyMask);

})(jQuery);
```

The html code:

```
<inputdata-role="mymaskeddatepicker"data-bind="value: DateOfBirth"data-placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"/>
```

But, this code use the other data-role attribute, but I use the ASP.NET MVC Html Helpers and by default `data-role` is `datepicker`. What is best way to solve it?
Thanks.

PS.[JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/7JA74/10/)

Answer (score 0):

You have basically created a custom wiget. Either initialize your widget with JavaScript instead of MVC helpers, or implement your own MVC helper to go along with your custom widget.